# How to fit a grid to the center of a borderlayout in ZK

Tags: zk

I've tried everything. All I want is for my ZK grid to fit to the available space in the center of the borderlayout. If there is extra information in the grid I want the grid to scroll, not the center of the borderlayout. If I enter width="100%" and height="100%" for the grid, the width displays correctly, but the height extends well below the bottom of the page (out of sight). I thought borderlayout was supposed to adjust the height of center to height of page minus north minus south? Anybody got any clues?

Comment: As per ZK Grid [documentation][1]

> A grid can be scrollable if you specify the **height** attribute and there is not enough space to display all data


  [1]: http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Data/Grid#Scrollable_Grid

Answer (score 0):

From my experience its better to use `hflex` and `vflex` attributes with values set to "1" (or "true") to fit components to the space of parent components. And you can try to use it in combination with grid's `style="overflow: auto"`. 
Read [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/UI%20Patterns/Hflex%20and%20Vflex) ZK doc section for further info.